# Excel sorting time Issue

Tags: excel

I have the following formula to calculate the column call "Meet Time" :
[image]

I am trying to sort the entire column H by smallest to largest so that I can block off times every 6 hours.  Every calculation that passes the midnight time seems to not sort with all the times that don't pass the midnight time.  What am I missing?  I feel like this is super simple and I am over thinking it.

[image]

Comment: once it passed midnight there is an integer of `1` added to the number.  That is why it sorts the way you see.  If you want to sort it by the time only you will need to deal with the integer portion.

Comment: Ok, do I do that with an if statement to reduce it by 1?  Sorry, not familiar with this.

Comment: `G60+(F60/24)-INT(G60+(F60/24))`

Comment: Separate your time into hour/minute and sort by the dual columns is another option.

Comment: @ScottCraner this is perfect.  I am not sure I would have thought of that.  Thank you!